# Polymeric sand issue

Tags: pavers

I dropped Goo gone on pavers. My husband had put the poly sand between pavers only 7 hours earlier. I thought they were dry and scrubbed the pavers that I stained then hosed the are off, washing out some of the sand!! Now it looks awful! How can he fix it?

Comment: depends on what `looks awful` actually means ... if it is missing sand, then add sand

Comment: The polymeric sand can be replaced.  Is the “looks awful” due to discoloration of the pavers?

Comment: Love the "how can he fix it"...

Comment: A photo would be helpful here.